# $sum from documents and subdocuments group by "$author" (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my collection:

```
{
        "_id" : 10926400,
        "votes": 131,
        "author": "Jesse",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "votes": 31,
                        "author": "Mirek"
                },
                {
                        "id": 2,
                        "votes": 13,
                        "author": "Leszke"
                }
        ]
},
{
        "_id" : 10926401,
        "votes": 75,
        "author": "Mirek",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "id" : 1,
                        "votes": 17,
                        "author": "Jesse"
                },
                {
                        "id": 2,
                        "votes": 29,
                        "author": "Mirek"
                }
        ]
}
```

And I want `$sum` values of `votes` and `comments.votes` of each `author`

expected output(`sort $votes: -1`):

```
"Mirek" total votes: 31 + 75 + 29 = 135

"Jesse" total votes: 131 + 17 = 148

"Leszke total votes: 13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not immediately visible but possible. What you need to do here is combine your top level document with the array of comments without duplicating it. Here's an approach to first join the content as two arrays into a singular array, then [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to group the content:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "author": { 
            "$addToSet": {
                "id": "$_id",
                "author": "$author",
                "votes": "$votes"
            }
        },
        "comments": { "$first": "$comments" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "combined": { "$setUnion": [ "$author", "$comments" ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$combined" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$combined.author",
        "votes": { "$sum": "$combined.votes" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "votes": -1 } }
])
```

Which gives the output:

```
{ "_id" : "Jesse", "votes" : 148 }
{ "_id" : "Mirek", "votes" : 135 }
{ "_id" : "Leszke", "votes" : 13 }
```

---

Even as skipping the first [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage and making a combined array a different way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "combined": { 
            "$setUnion": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": { "$literal": ["A"] },
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": { 
                        "author": "$author",
                        "votes": "$votes"
                    }
                }},
                "$comments"
            ] 
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$combined" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$combined.author",
        "votes": { "$sum": "$combined.votes" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "votes": -1 } }
])
```

---

Those use operators such as [**`$setUnion`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) and even [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) which were introduced as of MongoDB 2.6. This makes it simplier, but it can still be done in earlier versions lacking those operators, following much the same principles:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "author": 1,
        "votes": 1,
        "comments": 1,
        "type": { "$const": ["A","B"] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$unwind": "$comments" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": {
          "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$type", "A" ] },
              { 
                  "id": "$_id", 
                  "author": "$author",
                  "votes": "$votes"
              },
              "$comments"
          ]
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.author",
        "votes": { "$sum": "$_id.votes" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "votes": -1 } }
])
```

The **`$const`** is undocumented but present in all versions of MongoDB where the aggregation framework is present ( from 2.2 ). MongoDB 2.6 Introduced [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) which essentially links to the same underlying code. It's been used in two cases here to either provide a template element for an array, or as introducing an array to unwind in order to provide a "binary choice" between two actions.

Answer (score 2):

You could aggregate the results as below:

- `Unwind` the comments array.
- `Group` the records together to first calculate the sum of the votes
  received by each author in his comments. Meanwhile keep the original
  posts in tact.
- `Unwind` by the original post array.
- Now `project` the sum for each author.
- `Sort` by name and votes of the author.
- Select the first record from each group to eliminate duplicates.

Code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$comments"},
{$group:{"_id":null,
         "comments":{$push:"$comments"},
         "post":{$addToSet:{"author":"$author",
                            "votes":"$votes"}}}},
{$unwind:"$comments"},
{$group:{"_id":"$comments.author",
         "votes":{$sum:"$comments.votes"},
         "post":{$first:"$post"}}},
{$unwind:"$post"},
{$project:{"_id":1,
           "votes":{$cond:[{$eq:["$_id","$post.author"]},
                           {$add:["$votes","$post.votes"]},
                           "$votes"]}}},
{$sort:{"_id":-1,"votes":-1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id","votes":{$first:"$votes"}}}
])
```

Sample o/p:

```
{ "_id" : "Leszke", "votes" : 13 }
{ "_id" : "Jesse", "votes" : 148 }
{ "_id" : "Mirek", "votes" : 135 }
```