# Using functions for creating an index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a blog that allow users to vote for articles. The documents of an article looks like:

```
{
  title: "title of post",
  body: "text text text text text text",
  votes: [
    {user: "user1",  points:  2},
    {user: "user13", points:  1},
    {user: "user30", points:  1},
    {user: "user2",  points: -1},
    {user: "user51", points:  3},
  ],
  sum_of_votes: 6
}
```

I'd like to sort by the number of votes the post received. At the moment I added a field `sum_of_votes` that needs to be updated every time somebody voted. Since `votes` already contains the raw-data `for sum_of_votes` I thought there might be a more elegant way. I came up with two ideas:

1. Using a function while creating an index, for example:

   ```
   db.coll.ensureIndex({{$sum: votes.points}: 1})
   ```
2. Having a dynamic field. The document could look like this:

   ```
   {
     title: "title of post",
     body: "text text text text text text",
     votes: [
       {user: "user1",  points:  2},
       {user: "user13", points:  1},
       {user: "user30", points:  1},
       {user: "user2",  points: -1},
       {user: "user51", points:  3},
     ],
     sum_of_votes: {$sum: votes.points}
   }
   ```

In those cases I only had to update the votes-array. Is something like this possible in MongoDB?

Comment: Nope. There is no such thing as a "dynamic document", it means "aggregation" and if you want to use it on regular queries it is slow. Keep updating the field as you currently are. But I do think I have posted better structures than this for "upvote"/"downvote" handling on a few occasions.

Comment: Have you check save command http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/

Comment: Refer to @NeilLunn [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27883002) for a similar query

Comment: @chridam Wasn't what I was immediately thinking of but is pretty direct to this specific case. It's still better to store the total in the document. As with SQL, aggregation operations are all good, but you generally don't want to be using them in "live requests" when there would be a cheaper alternative. My specific mind here was more on a separation of "upvote"/"downvote" people fields. And of course the overall "tally" in a single field for the document.

Comment: @NeilLunn Good point! I was thinking perhaps an `$inc` operation on the `sum_of_votes` field on update?

Comment: That is the general idea if you are not doing it already. `{ "$inc": { "sum_of_votes": -1 } }` is the clear method for removal. The main point is to consider "how you decide" to make that update, as basically you don't want the same user voting more than once. Been covered a few times here though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you do the update on the votes array, either as updating the document by inserting a new vote in the votes array or updating an existing vote, an approach you could take is use the **[`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#inc)** operator on the `sum_of_votes` with the value you are using to update the `votes.points` with. For example, in the case where you are inserting a new vote for a user with value in variable `userId` and the actual vote points in variable `points` (which must be a number), you could try:

```
db.articles.update(
    {"_id" : article_id},
    {
        "$addToSet": {
            "votes": {
                "user": userId,
                "points" : points
            }
        },
        "$inc": { "sum_of_votes": points }
    }
)
```

And you will need to factor in Neil Lunn's point where you wouldn't want the same user to vote more than once in your updates.

Comment: Can I add the warning here that **`$addToSet`** will not add the same "user" and "points" combination, but neither will it just restrict the "user" alone or even stop the **`$inc`** operation where **`$addToSet`** does not actually add anything to the "set". The "sum_of_votes" will "always" be incremented. This matches the current structure. But that is what I mean by this is **not** the best structure for an "upvote/downvote" model.